# Timed Motion Sensor

Tags: smart-home, samsung-smartthings, home-security

I am wanting to setup an automated security function with our smart home setup.

Does anybody have any idea on how to setup a schedule to enable a motion sensor during a specific time?  I'm trying to setup an automation for our SmartThings motion sensor to alert me (by text would be great), turn on all the lights, and play an alarm from our Sonos speakers when motion is detected ***only*** between the hours of 11:00pm and 5:00am.

Here's the equipment we have:

- SmartThings Hub

  - SmartThings Motion sensor
  - SmartThings Multi sensor
- Google Home
- Nest Thermostat
- Philips Hue Hub

I also have the following applications:

- SmartThings app (ver 1.6.41-349)
- Philips Hue app
- Google Home app
- Nest
- IFTTT

I apologize if this seems rudimentary and basic for many of you, but I'm new to the Smart Home game and if it's not super clear and almost pre-done for me, I'm easily lost.

Comment: I suspect this question is kinda too broad for this site, but my personal recommendation is to cut your issue into the smallest sized pieces you can and then resolving them one by one. For instance, start by trying to understand how the [Smart Things Motion sensor](https://iot.stackexchange.com/search?q=SmartThings+Motion+sensor) works.  Get comfortable working with each of your components before you try sticking them all together.

Comment: Is there a better forum to post this on?

Comment: Hmm, probably not... it's probably best just to narrow it down a bit.  But you'll probably have to start working on it a bit and trying out various stuff so you know what kind of issues you're going to face.  Hey, why not take the [tour](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tour) and get your first badge, and you can check our [help center](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for more info about asking.  Welcome to the site, by the way!

Comment: But that said, I'd also wait and see how the community responds.  There may be someone who can get you going.  It's just that at the moment it's hard to come up with a concrete answer which tells you what to do, since there are probably dozens of steps, with multiple options and ways of doing things.

Comment: Sorry if this is a basic question, but it's not really clear - can you code?

Comment: My coding skills are... "basic".  I have a little experience with programming, but it really depends on what language.  C++, Java, and Powershell scripting is about the extent of it.

Comment: At this point, I don't think I need a specific answer, even a general direction or options would be good.  Something like "Have you tried using (SomeApp) or maybe (AnotherApp).  You could also do (RandomProcess).  Have you looked at (ThisForum)."  Anything like that would be a good starting point.